# can't download file from given information from mysql and set to content type

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i write a code for download a file and i give fileid for search in mysql and get information and get address of file to download, after read file information i can't get download file .
any body have any idea ?

```
$('#download').click(function(){
    $.post('ajaxAction/downloadProjectFile.php',{projectId:$('#projectId').val(),fileId:$(this).attr('alt'),userId:$('#userId').val()}, function(data){
    $('#message').html(data);
});





$content = readMyFile(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../projectFile/{$fileInfo['name']}");
header("Content-length: {$fileInfo['size']}");
header("Content-type: {$fileInfo['type']}");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$fileInfo['name']}");
echo $content;
```

Comment: Why do you have braces over your php variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use   $_POST['projectId'] &  $_POST['fileId']  &  $_POST['UserId']
to get informations in your php file ? 
and if you can just give me the error that apeare when you execute the code .

Comment: this code is noy have error, work . just can't get set content for download !